# Not able to iterate on API with chinese data

Tags: php, json, api, character-encoding

I have an API which returns json_encoded data, the data contains chinese characters, when I return the results obtained from the API I see json data, everything is normal so far, but when I try to json_decode the data it fails.

To debug the cause I encoded the data which I got from api and I see some special character before the api results starts: [image: see screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a BOM and a linebreak before the actual JSON…

Comment: @deceze any suggestion on how to fix this api side, I know the developer of the API